# Create ApplicationInsight TelemetryConfiguration without config file

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I dont know if it's posssible to create full TelemetryConfiguration without applicationInsight.config

I see there are TelemetryInitializers.Add it working well

but nothing for the configs

- TelemetryModules (present in config file but not on the class)
- DefaultTelemetrySink.TelemetryProcessors (present in the config file but there are no Add method in the class)

I serarched everywhere for an example of complete configuration via code but did not find anything. I want to get rid of the config file, because I want to use the TelemetryConfiguration in a common library. And don't want to pupulate many config files in end up librairies.

I looking in debug mode and seen many differences between class obtained with **TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault()** when I have the config file obtained from nuget package, and the one obtained when I have no config file. This is the reason of my question.

what I have sofar

```
internal class ApplicationInsightConfig
{
   public TelemetryConfiguration Config { get; }

   public ApplicationInsightConfig()
   {
      Config = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
      Config.InstrumentationKey = ConfigurationManager.GetSetting(new ConfigKey("ApplicationInsightKey"));
      Config.ApplicationIdProvider = new ApplicationInsightsApplicationIdProvider();
      Config.TelemetryChannel.DeveloperMode = false;
      DefineTelemetryInitializers();
      DefineDefaultTelemetrySink();
   }

   private void DefineDefaultTelemetrySink()
   {
      var tp = Config.DefaultTelemetrySink.TelemetryProcessors;
      Config.DefaultTelemetrySink.TelemetryChannel = new ServerTelemetryChannel();
   }

   private void DefineTelemetryInitializers()
   {
      Config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new AzureAppServiceRoleNameFromHostNameHeaderInitializer());
      Config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new HttpDependenciesParsingTelemetryInitializer());
      Config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new AzureRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer());
      Config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new BuildInfoConfigComponentVersionTelemetryInitializer());
      Config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new WebTestTelemetryInitializer());
      Config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new SyntheticUserAgentTelemetryInitializer { Filters = "search|spider|crawl|Bot|Monitor|AlwaysOn" });
      Config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer());
      Config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new OperationNameTelemetryInitializer());
      Config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new UserTelemetryInitializer());
      Config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new AuthenticatedUserIdTelemetryInitializer());
      Config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new AccountIdTelemetryInitializer());
      Config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new SessionTelemetryInitializer());
   }
}
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track. Setting the telemetry channel could be done slightly different:

```cs
TelemetryConfiguration config = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
config.InstrumentationKey = ConfigurationManager.GetSetting(new ConfigKey("ApplicationInsightKey"));
config.TelemetryChannel = new ServerTelemetryChannel { DeveloperMode = false };
```

Telemetry modules all implement `ITelemetryModule`, which defines a `void Initialize(TelemetryConfiguration configuration)` method to wire up the module:

```cs
var module = new UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule();
module.Initialize(config);
```

Telemetry processors can be added using the `TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder`:

```cs
var builder = config.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder;
builder.Use(next => new AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor(next));
builder.Build();
```

Then the final step is to use the config:

```cs
var telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

For those how want te final version here is the code :

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel;

//-------------------------------------------------------------
// Transcription code of the default ApplicationInsight.config
//-------------------------------------------------------------
internal class ApplicationInsightConfig
{
   public static TelemetryConfiguration Setup()
   {
      var config = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();

      config.InstrumentationKey = ConfigurationManager.GetSetting(new ConfigKey("ApplicationInsightKey"));
      config.TelemetryChannel = new ServerTelemetryChannel { DeveloperMode = false };

      //Setup TelemetryInitializers...
      InitTelemetryInitializer(config);

      //Setup Modules
      InitTelemetryModules(config);

      //Setup TelemetryProcessor
      InitTelemetryProcessor(config.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder);

      return config;
   }

   private static void InitTelemetryProcessor(TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder builder)
   {
      builder.Use(next => new QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor(next));
      builder.Use(next => new AutocollectedMetricsExtractor(next));
      builder.Use(next => new AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor(next) { MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond = 5, ExcludedTypes = "Event" });
      builder.Use(next => new AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor(next) {MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond = 5, IncludedTypes = "Event"});
      builder.Build();
   }

   private static void InitTelemetryModules(TelemetryConfiguration config)
   {
      new DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule
      {
         ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains =
         {
            "core.windows.net",
            "core.chinacloudapi.cn",
            "core.cloudapi.de",
            "core.usgovcloudapi.net"
         },
         IncludeDiagnosticSourceActivities =
         {
            "Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs",
            "Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus"
         }
      }.Initialize(config);
      new PerformanceCollectorModule().Initialize(config);
      new QuickPulseTelemetryModule().Initialize(config);
      new AppServicesHeartbeatTelemetryModule().Initialize(config);
      new AzureInstanceMetadataTelemetryModule().Initialize(config);
      new DeveloperModeWithDebuggerAttachedTelemetryModule().Initialize(config);
      new UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule().Initialize(config);
      new UnobservedExceptionTelemetryModule().Initialize(config);
      new RequestTrackingTelemetryModule
      {
         Handlers =
         {
            "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.RequestDataHttpHandler",
            "System.Web.StaticFileHandler",
            "System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader",
            "System.Web.Optimization.BundleHandler",
            "System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory",
            "System.Web.Handlers.TraceHandler",
            "System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryRequestHandler",
            "System.Web.HttpDebugHandler"
         }
      }.Initialize(config);
      new ExceptionTrackingTelemetryModule().Initialize(config);
      new AspNetDiagnosticTelemetryModule().Initialize(config);
   }

   private static void InitTelemetryInitializer(TelemetryConfiguration config)
   {
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new AzureAppServiceRoleNameFromHostNameHeaderInitializer());
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new HttpDependenciesParsingTelemetryInitializer());
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new AzureRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer());
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new BuildInfoConfigComponentVersionTelemetryInitializer());
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new WebTestTelemetryInitializer());
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new SyntheticUserAgentTelemetryInitializer { Filters = "search|spider|crawl|Bot|Monitor|AlwaysOn" });
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer());
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new OperationNameTelemetryInitializer());
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new UserTelemetryInitializer());
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new AuthenticatedUserIdTelemetryInitializer());
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new AccountIdTelemetryInitializer());
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new SessionTelemetryInitializer());
   }
}
```

Packages Nuget :

- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector (2.21.0+)
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector (2.21.0+)
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener (2.21.0+)
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web (2.21.0+)
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer (2.21.0+)
- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel (2.21.0+)

Comment: Hi @Francis,
We have followed the above steps to set the configuration. But we got some exception while reading the 'InitTelemetryModules'

System.EntryPointNotFoundException
HResult=0x80131523 Message=Entry point was not found. StackTrace: at  .DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule.PrepareFirstActivity() in  
/DependencyCollector/DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule.cs:line 288
at DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule.Initialize(TelemetryConfiguration configuration) in 
/DependencyCollector/DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule.cs:line 181

Pls suggest to us.

Comment: Hi @Naveen, with latests packages of Microsoft.ApplicationInsights there are some breaking changes you can try to apply modification. I posted my latests class modifications in this post.

Answer (score 0):

latest version of the class

```
public static class ApplicationInsightConfig
{
   internal static TelemetryConfiguration Setup()
   {
      var config = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();

      config.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString();
      config.TelemetryChannel = new ServerTelemetryChannel { DeveloperMode = false };

      //Setup TelemetryInitializers...
      InitTelemetryInitializer(config);

      //Setup Modules
      InitTelemetryModules(config);

      //Setup TelemetryProcessor
      InitTelemetryProcessor(config.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder);

      return config;
   }

   private static void InitTelemetryProcessor(TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder builder)
   {
      builder.Use(next => new QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor(next));
      builder.Use(next => new AutocollectedMetricsExtractor(next));
      builder.Use(next => new AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor(next) { MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond = 5, ExcludedTypes = "Event" });
      builder.Use(next => new AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor(next) {MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond = 5, IncludedTypes = "Event"});
      builder.Build();
   }

   private static void InitTelemetryModules(TelemetryConfiguration config)
   {
      new DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule
      {
         ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains =
         {
            "core.windows.net",
            "core.chinacloudapi.cn",
            "core.cloudapi.de",
            "core.usgovcloudapi.net"
         },
         IncludeDiagnosticSourceActivities =
         {
            "Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs",
            "Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus"
         }
      }.Initialize(config);
      new PerformanceCollectorModule().Initialize(config);
      new QuickPulseTelemetryModule().Initialize(config);
      new AppServicesHeartbeatTelemetryModule().Initialize(config);
      new AzureInstanceMetadataTelemetryModule().Initialize(config);
      new DeveloperModeWithDebuggerAttachedTelemetryModule().Initialize(config);
      new UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule().Initialize(config);
      new UnobservedExceptionTelemetryModule().Initialize(config);
      new RequestTrackingTelemetryModule
      {
         Handlers =
         {
            "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.RequestDataHttpHandler",
            "System.Web.StaticFileHandler",
            "System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader",
            "System.Web.Optimization.BundleHandler",
            "System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory",
            "System.Web.Handlers.TraceHandler",
            "System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryRequestHandler",
            "System.Web.HttpDebugHandler"
         }
      }.Initialize(config);
      new ExceptionTrackingTelemetryModule().Initialize(config);
      new AspNetDiagnosticTelemetryModule().Initialize(config);
   }

   private static void InitTelemetryInitializer(TelemetryConfiguration config)
   {
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new AzureAppServiceRoleNameFromHostNameHeaderInitializer());
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new HttpDependenciesParsingTelemetryInitializer());
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new AzureRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer());
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new BuildInfoConfigComponentVersionTelemetryInitializer());
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new WebTestTelemetryInitializer());
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new SyntheticUserAgentTelemetryInitializer { Filters = "search|spider|crawl|Bot|Monitor|AlwaysOn" });
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer());
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new OperationNameTelemetryInitializer());
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new UserTelemetryInitializer());
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new AuthenticatedUserIdTelemetryInitializer());
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new AccountIdTelemetryInitializer());
      config.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new SessionTelemetryInitializer());
   }

   public static string GetConnectionString()
   {
      var configKey = ConfigurationManager.GetSetting(new ConfigKey("ApplicationInsightKey"));

      if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(configKey)) configKey = "local";
      return $"InstrumentationKey={configKey};";
   } 
}
```