# Cannot instantiate Azure Application Insights TelemetryClient in a Xamarin app

Tags: azure, xamarin, azure-application-insights

What is wrong with this code in a Xamarin app? Is this some kind of compatibility issue?

```cs
string key = configurationWrapper.GetValue<string>("ApplicationInsights:InstrumentationKey");
TelemetryConfiguration config = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault(); // EXCEPTION!!!!!
config.InstrumentationKey = key;
_telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient(config);
```

UPDATE:

```
{System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
  at System.IO.Path.Combine (System.String path1, System.String path2) [0x00003] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/Path.cs:102 
  at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.Tracing.SelfDiagnostics.SelfDiagnosticsConfigParser.TryGetConfiguration (System.String& logDirectory, System.Int32& fileSizeInKB, System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventLevel& logLevel) [0x00017] in /_/BASE/src/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/Extensibility/Implementation/Tracing/SelfDiagnostics/SelfDiagnosticsConfigParser.cs:49 }
```

Comment: What is the stacktrace?

Comment: Hi @PeterBons . Updated the question with the only stacktrace I got.

Comment: It seems to be a compatibility problem. Because AppContext.BaseDirectory returns null and makes Path.Combine crash. =/

Answer (score 0):

`TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault()` tries to read the ApplicationInsights.config file, that is where it probably fails:

> Creates a new TelemetryConfiguration instance loaded from the ApplicationInsights.config file. If the configuration file does not exist, the new configuration instance is initialized with minimum defaults needed to send telemetry to Application Insights.

([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.extensibility.telemetryconfiguration.createdefault?view=azure-dotnet))

You could try using [`TelemetryConfiguration.CreateFromConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.extensibility.telemetryconfiguration.createfromconfiguration?view=azure-dotnet) which accepts an xml string that basically is the same as the content of the ApplicationInsights.config file.

Or instantiate the config using one of the public [constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.extensibility.telemetryconfiguration.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet) and configure the whole thing manually as outline [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72691639/create-applicationinsight-telemetryconfiguration-without-config-file)